# Video component YouTube elements are not clickable

Tags: sxa, javascript

On the video component when I input a YouTube video, the share, watch later, video title and up next sections are visible, but are not clickable, is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The video component is handled by `mediaelement.js`, you'll need to edit the JavaScript file for this service in order to fix this issue.

If you go to `/sitecore/media library/Base Themes/Core Libraries/scripts/mediaelement-and-player` and scroll down to the "media" section, download the `mediaelement-and-player.jsmediaelement-and-player.js` file there.

Copy this file somewhere to make a backup.

In order to make the default YouTube controls usable you need to turn off the "big play button" and stop the `Iframe` layer from being created, as it's putting divs in that cover the entire screen, preventing you from being able to click on the desired elements.

Comment out the following lines in the `mediaelement-and-player.js` file

1. `t.createIframeLayer();`
2. `bigPlay.className = t.options.classPrefix + 'overlay ' + t.options.classPrefix + 'layer ' + t.options.classPrefix + 'overlay-play';`
3. `bigPlay.innerHTML = '<div class="' + t.options.classPrefix + 'overlay-button" role="button" tabindex="0" ' + ('aria-label="' + _i18n2.default.t('mejs.play') + '" aria-pressed="false"></div>');`

Upload this file back to `/sitecore/media library/Base Themes/Core Libraries/scripts/mediaelement-and-player` and your video player elements will will now be clickable.

Comment: Thank you Jack for sharing. Do you have a confirmed support ticket number so this gets addressed in a future release?

Comment: No problem. I haven't raised a ticket with Sitecore support, this is a solution that I'd figured out when I ran into this issue. I don't have a certification yet so unfortunately I cannot raise tickets, I'd be happy to get a member of my team to do so if it would be useful, though!

Comment: The SXA has been really great about acknowledging reported defects and making sure they are fixed before new features. Submitting a ticket would be really helpful and including your solution will give them a great head start.

Comment: Perfect, I'll get a ticket submitted first thing tomorrow then! Thanks, Michael.

Comment: I've logged a support ticket containing the issue and solution, here's the ticket number: 533864

Comment: Does this solution still work for Sitecore 10.1. I have tried the above solution and does not seems to work for me.